# 500 error when trying to get source code of webpage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webclient

I'm trying to get the source code for a webpage that shows road conditions. The page loads just fine in IE and Firefox, but throws a 500 error when my program tries to access it. Why would it throw an error when my program tries to access it, but not when I open the page in a regular browser?

```
Dim rcrawtext As String
    rcrawtext = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://traveler.modot.org/report/modottext.aspx?type=condition")
```

Answer (score 0):

Their is nothing wrong with your query, the problem is the `URL` which you are using, it is not redirecting to a valid page

```
Dim rcrawtext As String
 rcrawtext = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837965/vb-net-500-error-when-trying-to-get-source-code-of-webpage-webpage-works-in-r")
```

Comment: I understand that it's not giving me a valid page or it wouldn't throw the 500 error. I'm able to get the source code manually in Firefox without a problem. Is there any way to get vb.net to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a `WebBrowser`?

Yes? Just use [`WebBrowser.DocumentText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Dim rcrawtext As String = WebBrowser1.DocumentText
```

No? Simply create one by code, without viewing it.

```
Dim WebBrowser1 As New WebBrowser

AddHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://traveler.modot.org/report/modottext.aspx?type=condition")

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    ' Same code above
End Sub
```